# creating a function that makes a new universum with all elements [0] PYTHON

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to create a function named create_empty_universum in matlab. This function will make a new universum with all elements on zero. This universum must have the n x m of a given matrix ( n length of a row, m length of a column)

for example.

```
I have a matrix m given.

I = len(m)                                  #I is the amount of rows 
J = len(m[0])                               #J is the amount of columns
New_matrix =[]
row= I*[0]
index = 0

def create_empty_universum():
    while index < J :
        New_matrix.append(row)
        index +=1
    return New_matrix
```

but my new matrix remains [] how does this come?

Comment: Your `return` is outside your function

Comment: Is it just me, or is naming a variable New quite disturbing?

Comment: I fixed the return problem. But my new matrix remains []

Comment: `index` is outside of the scope of `create_empty_universum` — how do you even call it? *Do* you even call it?

Comment: `New_matrix` <- every naming convention amalgamated into one? makeitstopmakeitstopmakeitstop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the multiply operator on a list:

```
>>> cols = 4
>>> rows = 3
>>> [0] * cols
[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [[0] * cols] * rows
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

If you really want to use a helper function:

```
def create_empty_universum(cols, rows, cell=0):
    return [[cell] * cols] * rows
```

#### Update:

See @tobias_k's comment: You should use `[[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]` to have unrelated rows.

Comment: Warning: Doing it this way, the matrix will contain three times the _same_ list, e.g. setting `M[0][0]` to 5 will also set `M[1][0]` and M[2][0]` to 5. To avoid this, use `[[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]`. (For the inner lists, the `*` operator is fine.)